# Matrix to imaginary product?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here's the question:

Find conditions on a, b, c, d ∈ R so that multiplication of \begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}
by the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{bmatrix}
is equivalent to multiplication of z = x + iy by a complex number w = α + iβ.
That is, compare the real and imaginary parts of zw = (x + iy)(α + iβ) with the
real and imaginary parts of $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}$
and find a, b, c, and d in terms of α and β.
How must a, b, c, and d be related to each other?

---

I can't really see how $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}$ even has an imaginary part. Once I can discover how the matrix product has a real and imaginary component, i suppose I would just compare the real part of the matrix with (xα-yβ) and the imaginary part with i(xβ+yα).
However, I can't do this without knowing how to come up with real and imaginary parts of the matrix product. Can you help with this please?

Comment: The point is that the matrix-vector product only needs to use real numbers and it simulates ("is isomorphic to") multiplying complex numbers. In the resulting vector, just as in the vector representing $z = x + i y$ that you began with, the top entry is the real part and the bottom entry is the imaginary part.

Comment: So in this case, i would then set ax+by=xα-yβ and cx+dy=xβ+yα (real=real, imaginary=imaginary) to see how a,b,c,d,α,β relate to one another. And when I do this, I get a=d=α and c=-b=β. Is my understanding sound?

Comment: @Brooke Yes, that's it. :)

Comment: thanks so much!!! @SammyBlack

Comment: thanks so much!!! @blakedylanmusic